# Getting selected item from ul li jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am poulating a list in ul - li HTML tag dynamically. All I need is to get value of selected li of corresponding ul. I tried all possible jquery methods I got but still i am getting undefined.I am populating ul - li as:

```
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {        
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            //console.log(data[i])  //"+data[i]+"
            msg = "<li> <a href=#>"+data[i]+"</a></li>";
            document.querySelector('#option1').innerHTML +=  msg;
        }           
    });
```

HTML section is as:

```
<body>  
 <div class="wrap">    
 <div class="content">
 <div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option1" onclick="doSelection()">       
    </ul>       
  </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="content2">
  <div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option2">       
    </ul>       
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="clear"></div>    
<div class="content3">  <textarea id="content4"></textarea>    
</div>    
</div>
</body>
```

onclick method is as :

```
function doSelection(){
    var id = $('#option1 li.selected').attr('value');
    alert(id);      
}
```

Problem is that I am getting 'undefined' for id value.

**UPDATE**

As you all suggested I changed my code as:

Populating ul as:

```
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            msg = "<li data-input="+data[i]+" class='selected'> <a href=#>"+data[i]+"</a></li>";
            document.querySelector('#option1').innerHTML +=  msg;
        }

    });
```

HTML ul as:

```
<div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option1"  onclick="doSelection()">

    </ul>

    </div>
```

Onclick function as:

```
function doSelection(){
    alert($('#option1 li.selected').attr('data-input'));

}
```

Now I am getting a value as alert but I am getting the first element as alert always. Whichever element I click still always getting the first element of list. Please do help.

Comment: could u provide the complete html inside ur ul

Comment: `<li>` elements do not have `value` attributes.

Comment: Any time you add class `selected` and a `value` to the wanted `li` ?

Comment: I have updated with comple body. Please NOTE I have used JSP page not HTML.

Comment: You don't have `li` that has classname `selected`.

Comment: Do you mean `$('#option1 li.selected').text()`? `value` makes no sense in terms of an `li` in a `ul` and you aren't adding that attribute when you create the `li`s anyway.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi `<li>` actually has `value` attribute, if its parent is `<ol>` http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li.attrs.value off-topic though

Comment: @crv Read the comments first . There are two problems in your code . Firstly `li` elements do not have `value` attributes . Secondly they don't have `selected` class .

Comment: i am trying with value attribute added. Let me check if it works.

Comment: @Leo, ah, true, true. I probably should have said *your* `<li>` elements do not have `value` attributes :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Guess I was a little harsh. It doesn't really have anything to do with this question. Off topic way too far :)

Comment: @Leo, no problem at all. You were right to point this out since my comment implies `<li>` elements can never have values, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You need add `selected` class to any `li` element.
Check it out:

```
msg = "<li class="selected"> <a href=#>"+data[i]+"</a></li>";
```

And get the content of anchor tag:

```
function doSelection(){
    var id = $('ul#option1 > li.selected a').text();
    alert(id);

}
```

Comment: You have any `li` with `selected` class?

Comment: I update the answer changing the selector. I try and works for me

Answer (score 2):

As you see in the comment from @Frédéric Hamidi `value` attribute is not there for `li` when it is used with `ul` so better add your own attribute to it then access it like this:

```js
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){// use actual data it is just a demo
        msg = "<li data-input="+i+" class='selected'> <a href=#>"+i+"</a></li>";
        document.querySelector('#option1').innerHTML +=  msg;
    } 

    $('#option1 li').click(function(){
     //console.log($(this).attr('data-input'));
        alert($(this).attr('data-input')); // this will alert data-input value.
         
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

<div class="content">
 <div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option1">

    </ul>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="content2">
 <div class="cate-map">
    <ul id="option2">

    </ul>

    </div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="content3">  <textarea id="content4"></textarea>
```

Comment: i tried ur code . but this time on click event is not working. I dnt knw wats problem. Is it because i am dynamically generating the list??

Comment: i'm also dynamically generating. run the code snippet.

Comment: just follow the way i have done it will work.try to log your data and see if it is proper.

Comment: it seems like .on() jquery function is not working in mine. are you using just https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js or anything more??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67119/discussion-between-crv-and-suchit).

Answer (score 1):

This will help you. You can use jquery method for handling selection event.

```
 $("#option1 li").click(function() {
     alert($(this).html());
 });
```