# How to dynamically create nested list using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

I'm new to web development and I'm sort of stuck with this. I have the idea in mind but I don't know how to formulate it using jQuery. I have an unordered list which should be updated with a listitem every time a button is clicked. If a listitem is highlighted, then I click the Add button, it should create a sublist inside that li. Sample markup is:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
                addExpression();
            });

            function addExpression() {
                var mainList = document.getElementById("mainList");
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var alink = document.createElement("a");
                var str = document.createTextNode("test");
                alink.appendChild(str);
                li.appendChild(alink);
                mainList.appendChild(li);

            }

            function createSublist() {
                var sublist = document.createElement("ul");
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                var alink = document.createElement("a");
                var str = document.createTextNode("test");
                alink.appendChild(str);
                li.appendChild(alink);
                sublist.appendChild(li);
                return sublist;
            }

            $(document).on("click", "ul.expression li", function () {
                $("ul.expression li").removeClass("highlight");
                $(this).addClass("highlight");
            });

        });
```

```css
 .expression ul {
            list-style: none;
        }

        .expression li {  
            width: 25%;
            height: 50px;   
            text-align: center;
            color: #B84DFF;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
        }

        .expression li.highlight {
            background-color: cyan;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .hide {
            display: none;
        }
```

```html
<button id="btnAdd">Add</button>
    <div id="containerDiv">
        <ul id="mainList" class="expression">

        </ul>
</div>
```

My main problem is how to get the selected list item so that I can correctly insert a sublist inside it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27523379/getting-selected-item-from-ul-li-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you place the "highlight" class on the selected list item, you can use that to get the selected item, like this:

```
var $list = $("#mainList");
var $selectedItem = $list.children('li.highlight:first');
if ($selectedItem.length > 0) {
    // There is a selected item.
} else {
    // There is no selected item.
}
```

You can do something similar to check if the selected item already has a `<ul>` inside it, or if it needs one added.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffdh2grL/1/)

Comment: Oh gee. Thank you. :) I never thought of that. Now, all I need is how to style it to appear like a tree. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use your function outside of $(document).ready(),also use jquery is easy and short !!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
          $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
            addExpression();
          });
          $("body").on("click", "ul.expression li", function () {
             $("ul.expression li").removeClass("highlight");
             $(this).addClass("highlight");
             });
        });
        function addExpression() {
            $('ul#mainList').append("<li><a>test</a></li)");
        }
```

Do other also like this...

http://jsfiddle.net/85aw5rwv/1/

Comment: Why move the function outside of `$(document).ready()`? That puts it in the global scope for no reason.

Comment: Put it outside if it's a reusable component so you could easily move it in a separate file and call from different contexts.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm new to everything about web development. Your inputs are appreciated. :D